# Working with times without dates

Tags: cocoa-touch, time, nsdate

An `NSDate` object represents an absolute date and time, e.g. September 4, 2012, 10:00PM CDT. While this works fine when an event did indeed happen at a certain moment in time, it's much more of a hassle to work with `NSDate` when you're dealing with something that's a recurring event. For example, I'm currently working on an app that stores the hours of operation of businesses. Most businesses have a weekly schedule, which means that I would like to store the times per weekday, regardless of the date.

There are several solutions: create an extra entity (I'm working with Core Data), Hours, with attributes weekday, hour, and minute and figure it out that way. This could work for simple displaying, but I'm also going to add a "status" (such as "open until x", "closing in y minutes", or "will open at z"). This means I'll either have to create `NSDate` objects to do the comparing, or I take the weekday, hour, and minute properties of the current `NSDate`.

Another option would be to store two `NSDate`s per business (open and close), and ignore the actual date and only use the weekday, hour, and minute properties. I've tried this, but to be able to compare dates, I'd still have to manipulate `NSDate` objects.

These are the solutions I've come up with. Both require a lot of math and involve a bunch of ifs, buts, and maybes. It would be really easy to simply have some sort of "NSTime" object with which I can do everything, but that doesn't (seem to) exist.

Has anyone else had the same problems and found a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're better off creating your own abstractions. That will better fit with the problem you're trying to solve. Some pointers for help:

- Fowler's [recurring events for calendars (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf) patterns.
- [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube): A ruby library for recurring events (for the design idea).

Comment: This is also something I briefly considered, but it just seems like it's so much work for something this "trivial". All I want is to store a time, that shouldn't be this hard, right?

Comment: No, you don't want to just "store a time", you want all that other stuff you described.

Comment: @Scott: just create the minimum code that you need (not more), encapsulated in a proper interface.

Comment: @KurtRevis: "All that other stuff" is some simple time comparisons. Shouldn't be this hard. I will give this a try, though.

Answer (score 2):

> It would be really easy to simply have some sort of "NSTime" object
>   with which I can do everything, but that doesn't (seem to) exist.

One option is to use NSDateComponents, in which you can store just the parts of a date that you're interested in, like hours, minutes, and seconds.

Since you really just want to store a time of day, another option is to create your own Time class. NSDate stores moments in time as a single number: the number of seconds since a fixed time, the epoch. Your Time class could do nearly the same thing, except that it would use midnight as the reference point. You may run into problems, though, if you're not able to indicate times beyond the end of the day. For example, if a restaurant stays open until 2am, you might want to be able to represent that relative to the day when the restaurant opened. Perhaps a better option is to have your Time class use NSDate internally, but always with a fixed starting date.

Comment: I would try with `NSDateComponents` first thing.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be too much work to write some methods to directly compare `NSDateComponents` objects. Will give this a shot as well.